# What happens to a block of Bitcoin blockchain if the Block size of 1mb is reached before the release of the next block

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

I recently got to know that the block size of Bitcoin is 1mb and a block of bitcoin is mined roughly about every 10mins.

My question is that what happens if the current block gets filled with 1mb worth of data before the next block is mined? Does the data about the remaining transactions not get added to the blockchain until the next block is released and the transactions fail? or am I missing a key point about how the data is stored in the blocks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the key point, nothing gets filled in between blocks generation.

Transactions appear in the network, and nodes validate them, and store in their memory, if valid (this set of unconfirmed transactions called mempool). The order, in which they appear in the network, doesn't matter. Miners decide which transactions they include in the next block.

They can include zero transactions. They can include all (if their size doesn't exceed limit). They can sort them by fee/size, and include the highest. They can include transactions of their friends with zero fee, and don't include foes with extreme high fee.

Comment: So if I get this right, I can initiate a transaction to send to a friend for 1BTC but it won't get added to the current block's data unless the miners decide to add the my transaction info to the blockchain? and if the block size is already at 1mb then the information is added to the next block?

Comment: @pi2018 If miners block template has reached limit, and your transaction has good fee, they will remove transaction from block with lower fee, and add yours instead.

Comment: Thanks! you seem to have a pretty solid foundation on Blockchain. Can you recommend books or study materials I should use in order to learn how to develop a blockchain?

Comment: @pi2018 you can start with bitcoin wiki. You can also check bitcoin/ethereum stackexchange branches here, there are a lot of questions and good answers.